# How to query Elasticseach using DateRange on a nested array?

Tags: c#, .net, database, elasticsearch

So basically this is the code

```
var filter = new QueryContainerDescriptor<GrossReservationVersion2>()
                    .DateRange(range => range
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(start)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(end)
                        .Field(f => f.BookingItems.First().Start)
                    );
```

now, BookingItems is a nested array, and in each item there is a start date. I want to filter using DateRange on the date within the nested array objects. Obviously this code won't yield any results. Any body knows how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here what I did..and it should work. You need to go to down the nested level then aggregate and use DateRange. You can use resversnested to aggregate on root documents once you wrote your DateRange.

```
 .Aggregations(a0 => a0
      .Nested("nested", n => n
         .Path(p => p.BookingItems)
               .Aggregations(a1 => a1
                    .Filter("arrival", f => f
                       .Filter(af => af
                          .DateRange(range => range
                            .Field(df => df.BookingItems.Min(d => d.Start))
                            .GreaterThanOrEquals(start)
                            .LessThanOrEquals(end)))
                              .Aggregations(a2 => a2                                                                    
                                .ReverseNested("reverseNested", rn => rn
                                   .Aggregations(a4 => a4                
                                      .Sum("worthAccumalative", s => s.Field(f3 => f3.worth))
                                         )
                                  )
                                         .TopHits("tHits", th => th
                                           .Size(10))
                                    )
                           )
                      )
                 )
             )
```

And as you can see, you can use TopHits to confirm your filtering and that you getting the right documents.